# UICollectionView: Different numbers of cells in different section

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview

How to show different number of cells in different sections of UICollectionView. Please provide any example for that.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
for(int i=0; i<[arrSeatSel count]; i++)
{
    int c;
    NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrSeatSel objectAtIndex:i]];
    c = [cnt intValue];
    return c;
}
return 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show what out put you want...

Comment: @ SAMIR RATHOD I want that each section have different number of cells, i have an array that contains values 3, 6, 5, these are number of cells in each section required. and an array that contains items in it counts 3 means number of sections is 3. hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done this way

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"vals count:%d", [arrSeats count]);
for(int i=0; i<[arrLevels count]; i++)
{
    if(section == i)
    {
        int c;
        NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTot objectAtIndex:i]];
        c = [cnt intValue];
        return c;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this  UICollectionView Datasource and Delegate method

```
   - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

       if (section==1) {

            return [arrSearchCelebs count]; // your array count.

       }
       else if (section==2){
           return 2;
       }
       else {
           return 5;
       }
    }
```

it is same as UITableView's delegate and datasource method..

Comment: ok, but at which section you want to add more row. you not specify your section in your coding. it return C for all section.

Comment: @ SAMIR RATHOD  i have two arrays one for sections and one for cells each section has different number of cells how to put that condition i am not getting.

Comment: @ SAMIR RATHOD array count will be number of sections. array have items in it.